# Can the parse.com server work with the Universal image Loader?

Tags: android, parse-platform, universal-image-loader

I have been using the parse android api creating an app. I've found out here https://parse.com/questions/image-caching-for-android that the Android SDK does not currently cache ParseFiles to disk.

Can the parse.com server work with the Universal image Loader to cache images in an android device before displaying them?

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the `URL` of that image by using method,

```
 image.getUrl();
```

Save into a separate variable & set that variable as a parameter for image path in `Universal Image Loader` method which displays image asynchronously.

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

`imageUri` is the file path which we got from `image.getUrl()`.

Comment: Thanks,  I tested this, it works but I ended up using the android open source image caching methods.